# Display list of values in same column in Looker Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, calculated-field

I'm pretty new to Looker Studio and formulas and haven't been able to find anything that can help me with the particular challenge I'm facing.

I have page paths with multiple queries. For example:

`/locations?community[]=32&search=Nursing&type_of_service[]=250&type_of_service[]=256&type_of_service[]=273`

As you can see, there are three `type_of_service[]` queries, each with a different number. The number corresponds to a text label. So, for instance, `250` could correspond to `Long term care`.

I want to have a **Type of service** column that lists all the text labels used in the URL. So, the output would look something like:

| Type of service |
| --- |
| Long term care, continuing care, acute care |

So far, I've only created a **Location queries** parameter for my data source:

```
--Location parameter extracts everything after the '?' in the page path
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Page path + query string, 'locations')
  THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page path + query string, r'\?(.*)')
  ELSE '(not used)'
END
```

Then I created a **Type of care** dimension:

```
CASE
  WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Location queries, 'type_of_care') THEN
  CASE
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Location queries, '250') THEN 'Long term care'
  END
END
```

But now I don't know how to add the other labels from the other `type_of_service[]` queries.

Am I going about this the wrong way?